# VB6 : Compile Error Type Mismatch

Tags: vb6

I have a large problem that I have yet to solve since I had it 2 days ago.

```
Private Sub mnuBackPic_Click()
CommonDialog.Filter = "JPEG Photo (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files|*.*"
CommonDialog.ShowOpen
Mother.Picture = CommonDialog.FileName
End Sub
```

The term .Filename kept getting highlighted for reasons I do not know.

Please note that Mother is an MDI Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the * on the line which gives the error, and use LoadPicture():

```
Mother.Picture = LoadPicture(CommonDialog.FileName)
```